# get(int) in List cannot be applied to java.lang.String

Tags: java

I created a Map like so:

```
private Vector vaildateTestScore(String persTestCode, String score, List<TSpecialTest> specialTestList, Vector errorVtr) {

        Map<String, TSpecialTest> specialTestmap = new HashMap<String, TSpecialTest>();

        for (TSpecialTest specialTest : specialTestList) {
            specialTestmap.put(persTestCode,specialTest);
        }

        if (specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin() < score){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestList.get(persTestCode)+" max range is "+" "+specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax());

            System.out.println("There was an error with > "+specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }
        else if(specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax() > score){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd()+" min range is "+" "+specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin());

            System.out.println("There was an error with < "+specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }

        return errorVtr;
    }
```

However where ever you see `persTestCode` my IDE shows a runtime error saying: `get(int) in List cannot be applied to java.lang.String`

This class is set up by calling the following at the beginning of the class like so:

```
   SpecialTestImpl specialTest = ComponentBuilder.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getBean(SpecialTestImpl.class);

     List<TSpecialTest> specialTestList = specialTest.specialTestList();
```

Then the method is called like so:

```
String persTestCode = elem.replace("scr.", "");
                                String score = request.getParameter(elem);
    Vector errorVtr = new Vector();

    //validates inputted test scores
    vaildateTestScore(persTestCode, score, specialTestList,errorVtr);
```

--------------------SOLVED--------------------------------

This was a comlete oversite on my side. The tab button and the name similarity got the best of me. This is what I am trying to do.

```
 private Vector vaildateTestScore(String persTestCode, String score, List<TSpecialTest> specialTestList, Vector errorVtr) {

        Map<String, TSpecialTest> specialTestmap = new HashMap<String, TSpecialTest>();

        for (TSpecialTest specialTest : specialTestList) {
            specialTestmap.put(persTestCode,specialTest);
        }

        if (specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax() > Integer.parseInt(score)){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode)+" max range is "+" "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax());

            System.out.println("There was an error with > "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }
        else if(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax() > Integer.parseInt(score)){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd()+" min range is "+" "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin());

            System.out.println("There was an error with < "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }

        return errorVtr;
    }
```

Comment: The string `persTestCode` after `elem.replace("scr.", "")` represents an integer value?

Answer (score 1):

Java List `get()` method takes an integer as an index into the list, and returns the object at that index.  You might be confusing this with your map data structure which you add to at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1):

List just provide the mehtod of get(int index),you can't use get(instanceName) gain the instance which is named as instanceName .
supplement:
the way that you use map#put(key,value) are incorrect.i think you should read the java#api carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This was a complete oversite on myside. I let the tab button on my IDE get the best of me since `specialTestList` and `specialTestmap` are similiar names.

```
private Vector vaildateTestScore(String persTestCode, String score, List<TSpecialTest> specialTestList, Vector errorVtr) {

        Map<String, TSpecialTest> specialTestmap = new HashMap<String, TSpecialTest>();

        for (TSpecialTest specialTest : specialTestList) {
            specialTestmap.put(persTestCode,specialTest);
        }

        if (specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax() > Integer.parseInt(score)){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode)+" max range is "+" "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax());

            System.out.println("There was an error with > "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }
        else if(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMax() > Integer.parseInt(score)){

            errorVtr.add(specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd()+" min range is "+" "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin());

            System.out.println("There was an error with < "+specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPerTestTypeCd());
        }

        return errorVtr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`specialTestList.get(persTestCode)` is trying to call [`List#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) passing in a **`String`**, so of course that's going to fail.

Perhaps you meant to use the map `specialTestmap` instead; it will have a `get(String)` method, since you created the map as being keyed by `String`.

Also note that

```
if (specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin() < score){
```

...is comparing what I suspect is an `int` (the result of `getPersTestScrQyMin()`) with a **String** `score`.

And this loop is quite suspect:

```
for (TSpecialTest specialTest : specialTestList) {
    specialTestmap.put(persTestCode,specialTest);
}
```

You're repeatedly putting using the **same** key value, `persTestCode`. Subsequent puts will overwrite earlier ones, so the loop doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem very clear.

Using a `List<TSPecialTest>`, the only `get` function you can use is :

- `List#get(int)`

But you're trying to call the method `get` with a `String` as parameter.

Your goal was certainly to get the value from the list attached to the `String` instead of using the `List`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, don't know why I thought so.

Answer (score 0):

The List.get() method expects an integer index, you are passing a String value.

```
 if (specialTestList.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin() < score){
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)

You probably are looking to get an object from your map, like this:

```
 if (specialTestmap.get(persTestCode).getPersTestScrQyMin() < score){
```